# How to pull values from a table with no defining characteristics?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull part numbers from a cross-reference website but when I inspect the element the only tags used around the table are tr, td, tbody, and table, which are used many other places on the page. Currently I am using Beautiful soup and selenium, and I am looking into using lxml.html for its xpath tool, but I cant seem to get beautiful soup to work with it.

The website I trying to pull values from is 
https://jdparts.deere.com/servlet/com.deere.u90.jdparts.view.servlets.searchcontroller.PartialPartNumberSearchController?action=UNSIGNED_VIEW
and technically I only want the Part Number, Make, Part No, Part Type, and Description Values, but I can deal with getting the whole table.

When I use

```
html2 = browser.page_source
source = soup(html2, 'html.parser')
for article in source.find_all('td', valign='middle'):
    PartNumber = article.text.strip()
        number.append(PartNumber)
```

it gives me all the values on the page and several blank values all in a single line of text, which would be just as much work to sift through as just manually pulling the values.

Ultimately I am hoping to get the values in the table and formatted to look like the table and I can just delete the columns I don't need. What would be the best way to go about gathering the information in the table?

Comment: Can you post the entire code? Only this chunk isn't helping much.

Comment: Is there a part number we are supposed to be entering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to find the `Qty.` which is an element at the start of the table you want and to then look for the previous table. You could then iterate over the `tr` elements and produce a row of values from all the `td` elements in each row.

The Python [`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html?highlight=itemgetter#operator.itemgetter) function could be useful here, as it lets you extract the elements you want (in any order) from a bigger list. In this example, I have chosen items `1,2,3,4,5`, but if say `Make` wasn't needed, you could provide `1,3,4,5`.

The search results might have multiple pages of results, if this is the case it checks for a `Next Page` button and if present adjusts `params` to get the next page of results. This continues until no next page is found:

```
from operator import itemgetter
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


search_term = "AT2*"

params = {
    "userAction" : "search",
    "browse" : "",
    "screenName" : "partSearch",
    "priceIdx" : 1,
    "searchAppType" : "",
    "searchType" : "search",
    "partSearchNumber" : search_term,
    "pageIndex" : 1,
    "endPageIndex" : 100,
}

url = 'https://jdparts.deere.com/servlet/com.deere.u90.jdparts.view.servlets.searchcontroller.PartNumberSearch'
req_fields = itemgetter(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
page_index = 1
session = requests.Session()
start_row = 0

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    while True:
        print(f'Page {page_index}')

        req = session.post(url, params=params)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
        table = soup.find(text='Qty.').find_previous('table')

        for tr in table.find_all('tr')[start_row:]:
            row = req_fields([value.get_text(strip=True) for value in tr.find_all('td')])

            if row[0]:
                csv_output.writerow(row)

        if soup.find(text='Next Page'):
            start_row = 2

            params = {
                "userAction" : "NextPage",
                "browse" : "NextPage",
                "pageIndex" : page_index,
                "endPageIndex" : 15,
            }
            page_index += 1

        else:
            break
```

Which would give you an `output.csv` file starting:

```
Part Number,Make,Part No.,Part Type,Description
AT2,Kralinator,PMTF15013,Filters,Filter
AT2,Kralinator,PMTF15013J,Filters,Filter
AT20,Berco,T139464,Undercarriage All Makes,Spring Pin
AT20061,A&I Products,A-RE29882,Clutch,Clutch Disk
```

Note: This makes use of `requests` instead of using `selenium` as it will be much faster.

Comment: I am having a dickens of a time getting additional pages to propagate. I have tried sending the appropriate parameters, and it gets the page, but it has no content. Any thoughts?

Comment: The next page URL is a variation on the initial POST request. I have updated the script to show you how to do it. Also it is probably best to use `requests.Session()`